# Spring Transactional Dynamic routing not able to open new transaction

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I want to route to a different datasource .

I have a datasource config class which will get all db connection from admin table and do the DB configuration

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.xxx"},
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
public class DataSourceCfg {

private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/admin?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8&serverTimezone=UTC";
private static final String USER = "root";
private static final String PASSWORD = "root";

private final StringEncryptor stringEncryptor;

private final Map<Object, Object> targetDataSource = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DataSource companyDataSource() throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL, USER, PASSWORD);
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from sys_cmpy_data_src where sts_code = '1'");

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        log.info("creating company datasource :{}", resultSet.getString("cmpy_code"));
        SysCmpyDataSrc sysCmpyDataSrc = new SysCmpyDataSrc();
        sysCmpyDataSrc.setCmpyCode(resultSet.getString("cmpy_code"));
        sysCmpyDataSrc.setDbUrl(resultSet.getString("db_url"));
        sysCmpyDataSrc.setDbUsr(resultSet.getString("db_usr"));
        sysCmpyDataSrc.setDbPw(resultSet.getString("db_pw"));
        ...

        try {
            DataSource dataSource = createDataSource(sysCmpyDataSrc);
            targetDataSource.put(sysCmpyDataSrc.getCmpyCode(), dataSource);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("create datasource error, company code:{}", sysCmpyDataSrc.getCmpyCode(), e);
            throw e;
        }
    }

    RoutingDataSource routingDataSource = new RoutingDataSource(targetDataSource);
    routingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSource);
    routingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(targetDataSource.get("admin"));

    return routingDataSource;
}


private DataSource createDataSource(SysCmpyDataSrc dataSource) {
    log.info("begin create datasource:{}", dataSource.getCmpyCode());
    String usrnm = stringEncryptor.decrypt(dataSource.getDbUsr());
    String pw = stringEncryptor.decrypt(dataSource.getDbPw());

    String url = dataSource.getDbUrl();
    String driveClass = dataSource.getDrvCls();
    HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();
    try {
        hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl(url);
        hikariDataSource.setDriverClassName(driveClass);
        hikariDataSource.setUsername(usrnm);
        hikariDataSource.setPassword(pw);
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("init datasource error", e);
        throw e;
    }
    log.info("end create datasource:{}", dataSource.getCmpyCode());
    return hikariDataSource;
}


@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .packages("com.xxx")
            .persistenceUnit("default")
            .build();
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") final EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    return transactionManager;
}

}
```

And a DBCtxHldr class that will set datasource in ThreadLocal

```
public class DBCtxHldr {
// for current thread, thread safe
private static final ThreadLocal<String> ctxHolder = new ThreadLocal<>();

// change dataSource by merchant code
public static void setDtsrc(String dataSource) {
    ctxHolder.set(dataSource);
}

private DBCtxHldr() {
    throw new IllegalStateException("DBCtxHldr class should not be instantiate");
}

// get current thread's datasource 
public static String getDtsrc() {
    return ctxHolder.get();
}

// clear datasource
public static void clearDtsrc() {
    ctxHolder.remove();
}
}
```

And a RoutingDataSource class which extends AbstractRoutingDataSource

```
@Slf4j
public class RoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
private final Map<Object, Object> cmpyTargetDataSource;

public RoutingDataSource(Map<Object, Object> cmpyTargetDataSource) {
    this.cmpyTargetDataSource = cmpyTargetDataSource;
}

@Override
protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
    log.debug("looking for datasource");
    String dataSource = DBCtxHldr.getDtsrc();
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(dataSource)) {
        if (cmpyTargetDataSource.containsKey(dataSource)) {
            log.debug("current datasource：{}", dataSource);
        } else {
            log.error("datasource not exist：{}", dataSource);
            throw new ApiException(SysCodeEnum.UNKNOWN);
        }
    }
    log.debug("changed to datasource:{}", dataSource);
    return dataSource;
}
}
```

So i do a simple testing here

For example i call /login api and the first transaction open for datasource is "alpha"

then in the next line i set DBCtxHldr.setDtsrc("admin") to admin

then i call another service , i expected it will create a transaction for datasource is "admin"

But end up, it's using the previous transaction "alpha"

```
public CmoResult<SecAuthRspDto> login(@RequestBody SecUsrReqDto secUsrReqDto, HttpServletResponse response) {
    SecAuthRspDto resp = authSrv.lgn(secUsrReqDto);
    DBCtxHldr.setDtsrc("admin");
    SysCmpyCfg alpha = sysCmpyCfgSrv.findByCmpyCode("alpha");
    return CmoResult.success(resp);
}
```

I have debug into deeper code and i found out
org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl the physicalConnection is not null so it's using back the previous transaction which is "alpha"

[image]

From my understand the transaction should open a new one.
Eventhough i have tried to set propagation = REQUIRED_NEW it's still same.

**Update 1** :
The same piece of code, if i put in filter which before it route to controller it able to open a new transaction with datasource ="admin"

```
SecAuthRspDto resp = authSrv.lgn(secUsrReqDto);
DBCtxHldr.setDtsrc("admin");
SysCmpyCfg alpha = sysCmpyCfgSrv.findByCmpyCode("alpha");
```

**Update 2**:
Found some logs , it behave different here "Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction". The transaction is the first line after enter controller , howcome it found thread-bound EntityManager.
As i see from logs above all connection is closed "Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(xxxxx)] after transaction"

[image]